# Is Cython option --embed using just Python inside, and no performance gain?

Tags: python, c, performance, cython, executable

Cython has the CLI option `--embed` to create .c file to make executable file from just any `.py` file. For example:
`cython3 -3 --embed hello.py`

The result is `hello.c` and can be compiled with GCC:
`gcc hello.c -o hello -I... -L... -l...`

Run:
`./hello`

It does look interesting, however, is there **any performance gain** in the final executable file? Or it is just Python totally inside the executable file?

It is stated in Cython doc that Python Interpreter is embedded into the executable but not so clear.

Comment: What does the documentation say? Also, what is in the generated `hello.c`?

Comment: it says Python interpreter is embedded in, but i wasn't not so sure since pip has lots of modules and how could it pack them into the executable

Comment: cython `--embed` works for a single module. It isn't suitable for bundling dependencies.